# api is not working in iis 7.5

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis-7, asp.net-web-api

i am doing an mvc4 application

in that i have a api controller called LoginController in my Controller folder.

in the login view, when click on login button, that api controller method will called using

```
$.ajax({
                      url: "/api/Login/Authenticate?username=" + username + "&password=" + password,
                      type: "Get",
```

its working when running vs2008. i published this in my localhost, but when click on login button, this api is not calling.

`iis 7.5 detailed error 404.0 not found` is showing

if i use

```
url: "/wsm/api/Login/Authenticate?username=" + username + "&password=" + password,
```

then its working, `wsm is the root folder`, how can i get the same result without using the name of root folder

How can solve this

Comment: Check your controller's route mappings, as it might mention `wsm` in there somewhere. It might also be a fault with the IIS configuration. It's hard to tell what the problem might be.